# External Mocked method returns Null in the Actual Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

When I am testing the Mocked external call, I am not seeing the mocked value of report instead it is `Null` and my testing is failing. I can see the Mocked value (of report) in the Test Class but not in `BusinessServiceImpl` class and Application(Method Return) is not modified as I expected.

**My Expectation:** When I mock the External call in Impl class, mocked value should be available there and rest everything else happen as if real method was called to complete the Unit Testing.

Implementation code:

```
package com.core.business.service.dp.fulfillment;

import com.core.business.service.dp.payment.PaymentBusinessService;

public class BusinessServiceImpl implements BusinessService { // Actual Impl Class
    private PaymentBusinessService paymentBusinessService = PluginSystem.INSTANCE.getPluginInjector().getInstance(PaymentBusinessService.class);

    @Transactional( rollbackOn = Throwable.class)
    public Application  applicationValidation (final Deal deal) throws BasePersistenceException {
        Application application = (Application) ApplicationDTOFactory.eINSTANCE.createApplication();
        //External Call we want to Mock
        String report = paymentBusinessService.checkForCreditCardReport(deal.getId());
        if (report != null) {
            application.settingSomething(true); //report is Null and hence not reaching here
        }
        return application;
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
@Test(enabled = true)// Test Class
public void testReCalculatePrepaids() throws Exception {
    PaymentBusinessService paymentBusinessService = mock(PaymentBusinessService.class);
    //Mocking External Call
    when(paymentBusinessService.checkForCreditCardReport(this.deal.getId())).thenReturn(new String ("Decline by only Me"));
    String report = paymentBusinessService.checkForCreditCardReport(this.deal.getId());
    // Mocked value of report available here
    //Calling Impl Class whose one external call is mocked
    //Application is not modified as expected since report is Null in Impl class
    Application sc = BusinessService.applicationValidation(this.deal);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to see the Answer I received earlier, is it removed?
There I received a comment that I am calling the Mocked method twice, I removed the below line of code from Test Class but still report is Null in BusinessServiceImpl and my test is still failing.    String report = paymentBusinessService.checkForCreditCardReport( this.deal.getId());

Comment: You have asked this question before, and as stated that time. You are not using your mocked object in your external class. Hence `report` will be null. However, if `report` in your test is `null` then I got no idea.

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply.  "report" is not null in Test Class but in BusinessServiceImpl class. I am worndering if I have to modify my external class (which I may not have access too) for testing then what is the use of Mockito, I mean then instead of Mocking external call I can directly create a new report string and complete unit testing. Please let me know if I misunderstood your answer. Also I assumed that when you said External Class you meant PaymentBusinessService and not BusinessServiceImpl.

Comment: My comment got to long, so posted it as an answer. :/ Lets hope it doesn't get to much downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of Mockito is to isolate the tests. As in, when you are testing your `BusinessServiceImpl` you should mock all its dependencies.

This is exactly what you are trying to do with your example above. Now for the *mocking* to work, the mocked object has to be injected into the class you are trying to test, in this case the `BusinessServiceImpl`.

One way of doing this is by passing the dependecy by the contructor of the class, [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Or you could look at how it can be done with [`Spring` and `ReflectionTestUtils`.](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58444-Unit-testing-Autowire-and-Injecting-mock)

Answer (score 0):

I got it done and I am successfully able to get the Mocked value without touching the BusinessServiceImpl class at all. Steps I followed are:
1.   @Mock     PaymentBusinessService paymentBusinessService = mock(PaymentBusinessService.class);
2. @InjectMocks private PaymentBusinessService paymentBusinessService = PluginSystem.INSTANCE.getPluginInjector().getInstance(PaymentBusinessService.class);

And then simply ran the above test and I could see the value of report as "Decline by only Me" in the BusinessServiceImpl and my test case passed